# What is unique identity of an Internet connected device IP / MAC?

Tags: php, javascript

I am making a script that show popup only one time , then it will never show again on that device..

How is it possible to do this?

I have already tried by using cookies, but these can be deleted by the user and so the effect is limited.

Another question is what is wholly unique per device, IP Address or MAC Address?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve can not be done. Just let it go and be happy about cookies. ;)

Comment: Storing device information is so wrong.

Comment: Besides the cookie you cannot store much user side. Your side (server) you could save the client's IP address and check if it's been used already. But you know with *dhcp* & al. addresses change. MAC is a low level address used at the data link layer - you should not have access to the MAC address client side. Both (public) IP and MAC are unique at a given time.

Comment: @ring0 Public IPs are *not* unique at all. MACs *should* be unique but are only relevant at the local link level and do not travel across networks.

Comment: @deceze [**public** IPs are unique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) otherwise you would have routing issues... As for the MAC address, as I said in my comment above it is indeed used at the lowest lewel - however some locally installed applications dare to use it to identify a hardware. Browsers of course do not provide that info. [and on Linux you can change temporarily the MAC address of an interface to what you want!]

Comment: @ring0 Proxies, anyone? NAT? More than one machine may use a *public* IP at the same time and many machines have the same *local* IP (192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x) at any given time worldwide. Neither are unique!

Comment: @deceze 3rd time ... talking about **public** addresses. While 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x etc.. are **private** addresses.. A NATed network has private IPs that are of course not unique - but its WAN Internet address is public and unique.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that IP Addresses are unique *per network* and not *per device*. That's not to say anything about proxies or NAT; and regardless, it's not particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: @ring0 *Again*: NAT. Proxies. One public IP may very well, and often does, hide several distinct machines!

Comment: @ring0: It's WAN Internet address is public and unique to that particular Internet connection. But there are two problems: 1) He can't get the WAN IP address of the Internet connection, he can only get the source IP address of the HTTP request. 2) He didn't say once per Internet connection, he said once per Internet connected device.

Comment: @David thanks for the clarification - but for me, anyway, the IP address was not an option due to dhcp etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is a cookie. There's nothing 100% uniquely identifiable about a machine that you have access to in an HTTP request. Yes, cookies may be deleted by the user. This is deliberate, live with it.

Answer (score 3):

The 2 options that are most obvious are either Cookies or a flag on an Account (if your users are authenticated).

Even though you've mentioned that cookies can be deleted, it's still a reliable form of saying "I have done something for this client before". If the user deletes the cookies then there's a high chance they know what they're doing, and should be expecting to have to repeat tasks (such as logging into other websites too).

If your users are authenticated (namely: they have to login to your site/service), then you can easily store a flag saying that the user has already been shown the notification.

That way is of course more reliable, but relies on authentication. Long story short: You need to take what you can get, and cookies are your best bet to have some form of unique device ID.

Regarding your other question: Nothing is unique in reality. MAC Addresses (which you wouldn't have access to anyway) can be spoofed, and IPs can be shared.

Comment: Well, you can use DNA samples. Then you just have to watch out for twins. To make sure someone doesn't give you a sample from someone else, you should draw it personally.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Definitely. But if you were to disclose the location that DNA would be sampled from, they could spoof it for your tests too!

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Millions of Internet devices have `192.168.0.2` as their IP. So that's not unique. And MAC addresses aren't Internet things at all, they're Ethernet things.

If you explain your outer problem in more detail, there's probably a solution. But it sounds strangely bogus from what you've said already. The same person on two different devices should get the popup twice? But with two people on the same machine, the first person should get it only? It's hard to imagine a use case where you should go out of your way to ensure that.